# Presta Shop Switching Domain Issue

Tags: php, redirect, prestashop

I have a website made on Presta Shop CMS. I had it on my trial server. The installation and everything. It works and runs fine. I then copied (using FTP) every file from my trial server to the main domain. I did not install it on the main domain (bought from network solutions), but copied everything there. 
The issue is when i hit the main domain, it somewhat redirects me back to the trial server. I have checked and changed many of the default values. and many values in the database. But still havent had luck. Also made changes in the .htaccess file, still without any luck.

I do not want to go through the installation process again on my main domain.
You can check the site (main domain :- www.myworld-myhome.com, it will redirect you to hrm.com/esol/ )

Comment: Did you check all your .htacces files?

Comment: the htaccess file is automatically generated by prestashop . i had links in it of my trial server. but i changed and uploaded .. nothing happens. i commented everything in the htaccess. nothing happened.

Comment: I would suggest you get someone you trust to go through the files.  Without more information, information you can't provide, there is little else I believe.. I at least, can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read [here](http://www.addons-modules.com/prestashop-tips/tag/prestashop-domain-name/), the prestashop domain name is stored in the `ps_configuration` table.
So, to solve your problem, you should run this SQL query:

```
update ps_configuration 
set value='www.myworld-myhome.com' 
where name='PS_SHOP_DOMAIN';
```

You should also edit your `config/settings.inc.php` file and change:

```
define('__PS_BASE_URI__', '/esol/');
```

To:

```
define('__PS_BASE_URI__', '/');
```